# How to overlap image over the div, but still wrap text around an image?

Tags: html, css, text, overlap

#### Summary

I own a start-up online dating site in Germany (https://MeineNeueLiebe.de) and am stumped by my attempt to have an **image that spills over its containing div** but still have the text inside the div flow around the part of the image that is still inside the div.

#### Here's what I'm trying to achieve (funky ASCII art ahead)

```
+---- div -----------------+
| bla bla bla bla bla bla  |
| bla bla bla +--------------------+
| bla bla bla |                    |
| bla bla bla |                    |
| bla bla bla |        image       |  <-- image overlaps div
| bla bla bla |                    |
| bla bla bla |                    |
| bla bla bla +---------------------
| bla bla bla bla bla bla  |
| bla bla bla bla bla bla  |  <-- text wraps around image
| bla bla bla bla bla bla  |
+--------------------------+
```

You can see where I'm trying to achieve this on my landing page https://MeineNeueLiebe.de e.g. in the box with the title "Liebe I'm Mittelpunkt".

#### HTML:

```
<div class="widget_container LP-TextBoxes">
<h2>Liebe im Mittelpunkt</h2>
<div class="FP-image FP-image-heart"><img src="https://static.meineneueliebe.de/assets/images/FP-image-heart-star-150.png" alt="Liebe" /></div>
<p>Sie wollen sich auf Ihre Partnersuche konzentrieren und nicht auf die Bedienung komplexer Webseiten? Sie wollen trotzdem alle Funktionen, die eine moderne Partnervermittung zu bieten hat? Dann sind Sie bei <strong>MeineNeueLiebe.de</strong> genau richtig!</p>
</div>
```

#### CSS Code:

```
.LP-TextBoxes {
overflow: auto;
}

.FP-image {
display: block;
float: right;
padding-right: 10px;
}

.FP-image-heart {
width: 100px;
height: auto;
margin: 5px 10px 10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: As yet, you can't do that with CSS with any real browser support. It's coming `CSS  exclusions` & `CSS Shapes` but right now. Nope! - http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-exclusions/ - http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/shapes-module/

Comment: You could use a div with `float` for the text to wrap around it and then put `position: absolute;` on the Image to position it on top of the div you created first.

Comment: @NoahWetjen You can't get text to wrap a float like you describe.

Comment: Please read this - http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/css3-floats/originalsubmition.html - This answers all your questions. - @PeterLairo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way that might work using negative margins.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... 
    <div class="image-panel">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
    </div>
    Sed sitamet erat augue. Morbi consectetur...
</div>
```

apply the following CSS:

```css
.wrap {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    overflow: visible; /* Make sure overflow is visible... */
}
.image-panel {
    float: right;
    margin: 10px -150px 10px 10px;
}
```

Use a negative right margin on the floated element and it will project outside of the 
parent container.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ckkrU/

Comment: The negative margin to the right has the effect of increasing the overall width of the parent block.  As you shrink the browser window, you will see the horizontal bar appear when the right edge of the image contacts the right edge of the window.

Comment: Interesting but is it dynamic / responsive or does it just work because of the specific dimensions currently being used? **Honest question**...

Comment: I could have used relative dimensions like `width: 50%` and it would still behave the same way.  Hard to say how well this would integrate in a responsibe layout, depends on what else is on the page.

Comment: The two things that made it work were: (1) overflow: visible; in the container, and (2) the negative right margin. Thanks for you quick and excellent help!

BTW: Could you please add the overflow: visible; part of your other answer to this answer, so that the entire correct answer is in only one answer. I would then mark your complete answer as "accepted". Thanks.

Comment: @PeterLairo Updated the answer with comment, glad to help and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Set `.LP-TextBoxes`'s overflow to `visible` and make the width of the image wrapper smaller than the width of the image. Insert a dummy element `.fake_float` with a zero wodth to push the image wrapper down without altering the flow of the text:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aLZvb/4/)

```
.LP-TextBoxes {
    overflow: visible;
    background: lightGreen;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
}

.FP-image {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    clear:right;
}

.FP-image-heart {
    width: 90px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.fake_float {
    float: right;
    width: 0px;
    height: 40px; /* adjust height to position image wrapper */
}
```

If your design prevents using `overflow: visible` then I think you might be out of luck

Comment: The text will only wrap either top or bottom...not both (AFAIK) as is required.

Comment: Indeed...hence my original comment on the OQ. If it could be done with CSS (to emulate a print layout) we'd have been doing it years ago. :)

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/cLwYn/)**

css

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
p {
    padding:.625em 0;
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:20px;
}
#container {
    width:755px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.col {
    width:365px;
    padding:0 5px;
    float:left;
}
.ColSpace {
    width:175px;
    height:300px;
    padding:5px;
    float:right;
}
.ColOut {
    width:350px;
    height:300px;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
}
.ColOut span {
    width:350px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:.9em;
    font-weight:bold;
}
img {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="col">
        <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text<span class="ColSpace"><span class="ColOut"><span><img src="http://www.google.com/think/images/google-trends_tools_sm.jpg" alt=""> The Google Trends. </span></span>
            </span>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
        <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```